# Scroll action that start on the reply button on comment bring in reply box (Touch screen)

Tags: bug, blog

Today I read a StackOverflow blog post on mobile: [If everyone hates it, why is OOP still so widely spread?](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/09/02/if-everyone-hates-it-why-is-oop-still-so-widely-spread/?utm_source=Iterable&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=the_overflow_newsletter). After reading the article, I scroll down and read comments there.

The problem is when I scroll up/down using my finger, if the start position of the scroll action is over the <kbd>Reply</kbd> button, it bring the comment box without scrolling. As I have no intentaion to reply at all, this behavior make the reading quite disruptive.

If the scroll action start anywhere in the yellow box below, reply box will appear:

[image: Scroll start here]

I think the default action should be the same with anchor link: If you touch a link and release, it navigate to new page. If you touch a link, hold and move your finger up/down, the page should not navigate to new page, but scroll up/down follow suit instead.

Model: Samsung A8 Star
OS: Android 10
Browser: Chrome 85

Comment: Repro on FF 80.1.2, Android 10